# CUDA error with processing the image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, cuda

I'm trying to get black and white image as the output with color image as the input. I'm using an OpenCV to get the image and write the output, and CUDA to make the image black and white in kernel. I tried the same code, but without OpenCV, and it worked fine. But now the output is slightly different from what I really expect to get.

I think that CUDA code needs some modification to work with OpenCV. I worked a bit with it but failed to find the way to do that. Maybe somebody can give me an advice or modify my code, please? I'm really confused with this problem.

```
   __global__ void addMatrix(uchar4 *DataIn, unsigned char *DataOut)
    {
        int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        DataOut[idx] = (DataIn[idx].x + DataIn[idx].y + DataIn[idx].z)/3;
    }

int main() 
{
        cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, 0);

        char* c = "";
        printf("Input source of image\n Example of right directory file: E:\henrik-evensen-castle-valley-v03.jpg\n Your turn:\n");
        char *tbLEN;
        tbLEN = new char [1024];

        cin.getline(tbLEN,1024);

        cout<< endl << "Your image: " << tbLEN << endl;

        //Data for input image
        IplImage* image;
        image = cvLoadImage(tbLEN, 1);
        int height = image->height;
        int width = image->width;
        int step = image->widthStep;
        int SizeIn = (step*height);
        printf("\nProcessing image\n");
        //Data for output image
        IplImage *image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        int step2 = image2->widthStep;
        int SizeOut = step2 * height;

        //GPU
        uchar4* DatIn = (uchar4*)image->imageData;
        unsigned char* DatOut = (unsigned char*)image2->imageData;
        uchar4 *datIndev;
        unsigned char *datOutdev;

        printf("Allocating memory on Device\n");
        /* Allocate memory on Device */
        cudaMalloc(&datIndev, SizeIn * sizeof(unsigned char));
        cudaMalloc(&datOutdev, SizeOut * sizeof(unsigned char));

        printf("Copy data on Device\n");
        /* Copy data on Device */
        cudaMemcpy(datIndev, DatIn, SizeIn * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(datOutdev, DatOut, SizeOut * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        int NumThreadsX = deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock;
        int NumBlocksX = (width * height)/NumThreadsX;

        dim3 blocks(NumBlocksX, 1, 1);
        dim3 threads(NumThreadsX, 1, 1);
        addMatrix <<< blocks, threads >>> (datIndev, datOutdev);


        cudaMemcpy(DatOut, datOutdev, SizeOut * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cvNamedWindow("Imagecolor");
        cvShowImage("Imagecolor", image);

        cvNamedWindow("Gray");
        cvShowImage("Gray", image2);
        const char* filename1 = "CcPwSwMW4AELPUc.jpg";
        printf("Saving an output image\n");
        cvSaveImage( filename1, image2 );
        cudaFree(datOutdev);
        cudaFree(datIndev);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        return 0;
}
```

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

Comment: Maybe you want to verify that the actual step of the image, is such that you have 4 channels per pixel. At first sight, I would say image is 3 bytes per pixel, hence the uchar4 is not the adequate type.

Comment: I am pretty sure OpenCV just discards the alpha channel, so your have BGR and not BGRA data within the source image

Comment: `cvLoadImage` with flag 1 will be **BGR**, so you have **3** channels... If you want with alpha it should be -1 (and the image must have alpha). Also, I just wonder why you have `c++` tag if you are using `c` functions of opencv

Comment: So I need to edit cvLoadImage(tbLEN, -1); and it will work? Sorry for c++, edited that to c tag.

Comment: @api55: The question should be tag with C++ and not C because the code in the question is written in C++ and CUDA (which itself is a C++ dialect), and compilation is done with a C++ compiler. There is no C here.

Comment: @talonmies I agree with you in that. I think I should re phrase what I said to, I wonder, why you are using the OpenCV  C version of the functions when it is a c++ program :) (it is not wrong, I just wonder why) BTW, @Generwp: `cvLoadImage(tbLEN, -1);` may work **ONLY** if it is an image with an alpha channel. Otherwise, it will still be a BGR image. You can try checking if it loaded a type `CV_8UC4´ or ´CV_8UC3´. Or if the alpha channel is not needed, work with the 1 there and it will always be ´BGR´.

Comment: @api55 My mistake, it's because I started to learn OpenCV with course, which used C implementation of it. I'll surely proceed to C++ version now, thanks in advance :)

Maybe you can give me some links to read about alpha channel and image processing in OpenCV? It's still a big mystery for me, anyway thank you :)

Comment: @Generwp No problem, everything depends on what exactly you want to do. You have some tutorials in the OpenCV webpage. This [blog](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/p/learning-opencv-functions-step-by-step.html) may be useful to learn some beginner's stuff. About the alpha part, it is not well implemented in OpenCV, or so I heard.... The flag options can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvloadimage#imread) of the function. Also, some of the functions of OpenCV are already in CUDA :)

Comment: @Generwp one last thing, the tutorials can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) and the ones of image processing in [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc.html#table-of-content-imgproc)

Comment: Thank you a lot for help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. Your assumption about four channel data is incorrect. Your code will load a three channel BGR image into memory from file. So you need to change references from `uchar4` to `uchar`and then have each thread load three bytes from the source image within your kernel
2. Your kernel itself contains a potential arithmetic error. The sum of three unsigned char pixel values can overflow an unsigned char intermediate result and produce an incorrect average. You should use a larger type for the calculation.

Taken together, your kernel should look something like this:

```
__global__ void addMatrix(unsigned char *DataIn, unsigned char *DataOut)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int b = DataIn[3*idx];
    int g = DataIn[3*idx+1];
    int r = DataIn[3*idx+2];

    DataOut[idx] = (unsigned char)((b + r + g)/3);
}
```

Then you might find your image looks correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now what I was doing wrong, thank you a lot.